# DD reports success after seconds but nothing actually happens. Can't format USB, either (Debian 10)

Tags: debian, dd, usb-drive

DD returns

```
$ sudo dd if=Downloads/ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb
1871872+0 records in
1871872+0 records out
958398464 bytes (958 MB, 914 MiB) copied, 2.0311 s, 472 MB/s
```

after about two seconds. Attempting to format it with Disks (the GUI disk partitioner) returns stuff about /dev/sdb not being a block device. I seem to have fried it. I saw a recommendation for FixParts but couldn't get it to compile.

Comment: Hypothesis: [you created a regular file](https://superuser.com/a/1401537/432690) named `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: `file /dev/sdb` returns `block special (8/16)`. `file /dev/sdb1` and `file /dev/sdb2` return no such file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `/dev/sdb` is actually the correct block device for your USB stick, the data has been cached for writing but not yet written to the USB device.

You can verify that `/dev/sdb` is correct by checking that it disappears when you remove the USB stick, and reppears once more a few moments after reinserting the stick into your computer. If necessary, take a look at the last few lines from `dmesg` to see what device the kernel as assigned your USB device.

Once you have ascertained the correct device name, use this pair of commands to ensure that data has been completely written to the target device

```
sudo dd bs=16M if=Downloads/ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb
sync
```

Comment: It just randomly worked when I retried my original command before trying yours. I unmounted it, plugged it back in, and boom. Weird. I guess I shouldn't mark either reply as the answer and just leave this up.

Comment: @danstark The partitions should be umounted before `dd` , If not it will cause a similar problem.

Comment: @danstark nothing should have been mounted

Comment: Strange because it still seemed to work (the liveUSB booted fine at all, aside from it not being able to connect to the internet, but that's another issue I posted about on askubuntu). If it wouldn't have, I would've thought DD would throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `cp` as recommended by debian docs:

```
cp debian.iso /dev/sdaX
sync
```

[4.3.1. Preparing a USB stick using a hybrid CD or DVD image](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/ch04s03.html.en)

> Important

> Simply writing the CD or DVD image to USB like this should work fine for most users. The other options below are more complex, mainly for people with specialised needs.

With `dd` you nedd to determine the sector size:

```
isosize -x <device>
```

Then;

```
dd if=<file> of=<device> bs=<sector size>; sync
```

or:

```
dd if=<file> of=<device> bs=<sector size> status=progress oflag=sync
```

debian FAQ: [How can I verify the downloaded ISO images and written optical media?](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#verify)

> Checksums of already written optical media match those found in the checksum files. This is a slightly more difficult operation to describe.
> The problem with the verification of written optical media is that some media types will possibly return more bytes than those found in the ISO image. This trailing garbage is impossible to avoid with CD written in TAO mode, incrementally recorded DVD-R[W], formatted DVD-RW, DVD+RW, BD-RE, and also with USB keys. Therefore, we need to read exactly the same number of sectors of data from the media as are found in the ISO image itself; reading any more bytes from the media will alter the checksum result.

> The isosize program can be used to find out the appropriate amount of bytes to be read from the optical media. It shows the sector count and the sector size from the optical media, where  is the device file of the loaded optical media.

```
$ /sbin/isosize -x <device>
sector count: 25600, sector size: 2048
```

> Then sector count and sector size are passed to dd to read the appropriate amount of bytes from the optical media and the byte stream is then piped to the appropriate checksum tool (sha512sum, sha256sum, etc).

```
$ dd if=<device> count=<sector count> bs=<sector size> | sha512sum
```

Comment: Thanks, but check my comment to the other reply.